# Using unicode characters in Elasticsearch synonyms

Tags: unicode, elasticsearch

I am trying to setup elasticsearch index using synonyms and almost succeeded it. My configuration of index:

```
{
    "index": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "syns": {
                    "filter": [
                        "standard",
                        "lowercase",
                        "syns_filter"
                    ],
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard"
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "syns_filter": {
                    "type": "synonym",
                    "synonyms": ["Киев , Kyiv", "jee,java"],
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Only thing I could not solve is that it worked for `jee` and searches result output same results as for `java`, but does not work for `Kyiv`.